# Interface segregation principle application

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I'm wondering if the Interface segregation principle applys to my codebase.

Here's some example code:

First Class:

```
public class EntityGroup {
    public List<Entity> tests;

    //returns true if the EntityGroup is valid
    public boolean validate() {
        for (Entity test : tests) {
            if (!test.validateFieldA() || !test.validateFieldB()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Second Class:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    protected String fieldA;

    public abstract boolean validateFieldA();

    public abstract boolean validateFieldB();

}
```

Third Class:

```
public class EntityChild extends Entity {
    private String fieldB;


    @Override
    public boolean validateFieldA() {
        if (fieldA.equals("valid")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateFieldB() {
        if (fieldB.equals("valid")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Fourth Class:

```
 public class EntityChild2 extends Entity {

    @Override
    public boolean validateFieldA() {
        if (fieldA.equals("valid")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateFieldB() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is a greatly simplified example from my real codebase but I think it illustrates the problem well. My EntityChild2 class is forced to implement a method it does not need or want to know about.

I know that it would be more correct to have a Interface that would contain the validateFieldB() method and only have EntityChild implement that interface.

With the understanding that this would take a significant amount of effort to refactor into this solution,  I'm having a hard time justifying the time it would take to implement this solution in my real code base.

What potential problems will I run into down the line by leaving my code this way?

What benefits will I gain from refactoring my code to have a separate interface for validateFieldB()?

tldr: Why is the Interface Segregation Principle  so important?

Comment: You use the word `Interface` many times but do not use in your code - maybe a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

## Wrong Abstraction

You make use of the interface segregation principle but with wrong abstractions.. Your different `Entity`-types differ only in they behavior.

Because of the shared behavior you have duplicate code in the methods `validateFieldA` of `EntityChild` and `EntityChild2` . The method `validateFieldB` looks very similar to `validateFieldA` just the filed for checking the equality is an other.

## You only need one `Entity`

### Strategy Pattern

With the *[Strategy-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)* you will have no duplicate code:

```
class EqualValidationStategy() implements ValidationStategy<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean check(T a, T b) {
        return a.equals(b)
    }
}

class TrueValidationStategy() implements ValidationStategy<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean check(T a, T b) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Entity

```
public class Entity {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;
    private ValidationStategy<String> validationForA;
    private ValidationStategy<String> validationForB;

    // all-args consturctor

    @Override
    public boolean validateFieldA() {
        return validationForA.check(fieldA, "valid");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateFieldB() {
        return validationForB.check(fieldB, "valid");
    }
}



// Validates fieldA and "ignores" fieldB
Entity example = new Entity(fieldA, 
                            fieldB, 
                            new EqualValidationStategy(), 
                            new TrueValidationStategy());
```

Comment: Same problem, different implementation. You only switched inheritance for composition, but that doesn't really answer OP's question which is whether ISP was any useful so that sub-classes that only have `fieldA` would only have to implement such contract and the same for those who only have `fieldB`.